# How to sort data of txt file in Python

Tags: python, sorting

I have devices.txt file that looks like this:

```
tw004:Galaxy S5:Samsung:Mobilni telefon:5
tw002:Galaxy S6:Samsung:Mobilni telefon:1
tw001:Huawei P8:Huawei:Mobilni telefon:4
tw003:Huawei P9:Huawei:Mobilni telefon:3
```

Now, I have code like this, and I have to chose how to sort devices in table (for example sort them by code from tw001 to tw004 or sort them by producer's name from A to Z)

```
def formatheader():
        print(
    "Code |    Name    |  Producer  |       Description       |  Quantity   |\n"
    "-----+------------+------------+-------------------------+-------------|")

def sortbycode():
    devices = open('devices.txt', 'r')
    formatheader()
    for i in devices:
        devices = i.strip("\n").split(":")
        print("{0:5}|{1:13}|{2:15}|{3:18}|{4:5}".format(    
            devices[0],
            devices[1],
            devices[2],
            devices[3],
            devices[4]))
    print()
```

How to do that?

Comment: If you simply read all strings into a list of strings and call `sorted()` (with no keys, splitting, etc.), you'll have the list sorted by devices.

Comment: Yep that will do the job

Comment: Actually I have to choose what will be the key for sorting, code, name or producer. So if I choose to sort by Producer name from A to Z, then it will print me devices in table regadles of device's code.
I just thought if I figure out how to sort by code, I also understand how to sort by other parameters. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
def formatheader():
        print(
    "Code |    Name     |   Producer    |     Description  |  Quantity   |\n"
    "-----+-------------+---------------+------------------+-------------|")

def sortbycode():
    device_file = open('devices.txt', 'r')
    formatheader()
    devices = []
    for line in device_file:
        devices.append([i  for i in line.strip("\n").split(":")])
    devices.sort(key=lambda x:x[0])
    for device in devices:
      print("{0:5}|{1:13}|{2:15}|{3:18}|{4:5}".format(*device))
sortbycode()
```

Comment: thank's a lot. You saved me. That's exatcly what I looking for. That is concretely answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) method of lists:

```
devices.sort()
# or if you want to sort by another field, use a key function
devices.sort(key=lambda x:int(x[4])) # sort by integer value of quantity
```

You should use a different variable name in the `for` loop to avoid messing with `devices`. And, if you want to sort by another column, you will need to do the splitting each line of `devices` into a list before you loop over and print them. You may need two loops (the original for loop to print, and a while loop to process each line ready to sort)

Side note: for this use case, using `.strip()` without any arguments would be safer, as that will catch leading/trailing whitespace, as well as removing `'\r\n'` style line endings (if the file so happens to have them).

Also, since you know the list for each row will always be the same format, you could use `.format(*devices)` to [unpack the list to arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), which may be shorter or neater.